# How to debug Share contract in Metro app?

Tags: c#, debugging, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

How do I debug the Share contract in a Metro app?  I've tried both locally and the simulator.  The flyout opens and then disappears after clicking my app's share target button.  Currently I can only get the flyout to remain open if I launch the app from the Metro start screen, without debugging.

Answer (score 6):

Change your debug option in Visual Studio to not launch the application.

1. Right Click the project
2. Properties
3. Debugging
4. Launch Application = No
5. OK out
6. F5 **your app**
7. Share to it from the *other app*

VS should automatically attach when your process starts.

Comment: I've already tried this :(  As far as I can tell, this only stops your app from being launched when debugging starts.  As long as I'm debugging, if I go to any other app and attempt to share with my app, the share flyout appears with my app logo, but then disappears right away.  If I stop debugging, the share flyout appears normally.

Comment: That's the point -- it stops it *launching*, but when you do launch the app through whatever mechanism (protocol handler, share contract), it should launch & attach the debugger.

Sure you aren't just hitting a breakpoint in your app?

Comment: Yeah...  I deleted all breakpoints.  I get the same behaviour with the example ShareTarget app: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782

Comment: I have a hunch that when the debugger attaches, the share target flyout loses focus and closes.

Comment: Using the simulator should help you avoid the focus issues.

Comment: Just to follow up... I never got this to work even in the simulator.  I ended up debugging my app's sharing capabilities by explicitly calling by submit event handler.  The flyout opens and closes as soon I hit my app's icon from the share target list.